# Получение информации из XML

Tags: c#, xml

Есть XML файл, в нем два элемента <Раздел1.1>. Необходимо выдернуть из этого XML НомерЗаписи и Наим.ЮЛ (во втором блоке <Фам>) в консоль.

Я Десериализовал XML в объект, и получил необходимые данные, но первого элемента. Как получить все? Foreach не проканал.

Код:

```
ConsoleApp3.FSFM.СообщОтказ_115ФЗ Obj = new ConsoleApp3.FSFM.СообщОтказ_115ФЗ();
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(Obj.GetType());
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\load\\CB_ES550P_20171018_001.xml");

Obj = (ConsoleApp3.FSFM.СообщОтказ_115ФЗ)reader.Deserialize(file);

Console.WriteLine(Obj.ИнформЧасть[0].Раздел11[0].НомерЗаписи.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(Obj.ИнформЧасть[0].Раздел11[0].СведЮЛ.НаимЮЛ.ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
```

XML:

```
<СообщОтказ_115ФЗ>
    <СлужЧасть>
      <ВерсияФормата>1.1</ВерсияФормата>
      <ДатаСообщения>18/10/2017</ДатаСообщения>
      <ТелОператор>01234567890</ТелОператор>
      <ЭлектроннаяПочта>email@email.ru</ЭлектроннаяПочта>
    </СлужЧасть>
    <ИнформЧасть>
      <ТипОрганизация>КО</ТипОрганизация>
      <Раздел1.1>
        <НомерЗаписи>00000000000</НомерЗаписи>
        <ФорматЗаписи>4077</ФорматЗаписи>
        <ТипЗаписи>1</ТипЗаписи>
        <ПризнакИнф>1</ПризнакИнф>
        <КодОтказа>00</КодОтказа>
        <ДатаОтказа>31/08/2017</ДатаОтказа>
        <ТипКлиента>1</ТипКлиента>
        <ПризнакКлиента>1</ПризнакКлиента>
        <СведЮЛ>
          <НаимЮЛ>ООО РОГА И КОПЫТА</НаимЮЛ>
          <ИННЮЛ>0000000</ИННЮЛ>
          <КППЮЛ>000000</КППЮЛ>
          <ОГРНЮЛ>000000</ОГРНЮЛ>
          <АдрРегЮЛ>
            <КодОКСМ>0000</КодОКСМ>
            <СтранаНаименование>РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ</СтранаНаименование>
            <КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>000</КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>
            <Район>Какая-то область</Район>
            <Пункт>какой-то город</Пункт>
            <Улица>какая-то улица</Улица>
            <Дом>1</Дом>
            <Корп></Корп>
            <Оф></Оф>
          </АдрРегЮЛ>
          <АдрЮЛ>
            <КодОКСМ>0000</КодОКСМ>
            <СтранаНаименование>РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ</СтранаНаименование>
            <КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>0</КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>
            <Район>ОБЛ</Район>
            <Пункт>Г</Пункт>
            <Улица>УЛ</Улица>
            <Дом>0</Дом>
            <Корп></Корп>
            <Оф></Оф>
          </АдрЮЛ>
        </СведЮЛ>
      </Раздел1.1>
      <Раздел1.1>
        <НомерЗаписи>00000000001</НомерЗаписи>
        <ФорматЗаписи>4077</ФорматЗаписи>
        <ТипЗаписи>2</ТипЗаписи>
        <ПризнакИнф>0</ПризнакИнф>
        <КодОтказа>03</КодОтказа>
        <ДатаОтказа>11/10/2017</ДатаОтказа>
        <ТипКлиента>3</ТипКлиента>
        <ПризнакКлиента>1</ПризнакКлиента>
        <СведФЛИП>
          <ФИОФЛИП>
            <Фам>фамилия</Фам>
            <Имя>имя</Имя>
            <Отч>отчество</Отч>
          </ФИОФЛИП>
          <ИННФЛИП>000000</ИННФЛИП>
          <ОГРНИП>000000</ОГРНИП>
          <АдрРегИП>
            <КодОКСМ>000</КодОКСМ>
            <СтранаНаименование>Российская Федерация</СтранаНаименование>
            <КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>000</КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>
            <Район>р-н</Район>
            <Пункт>с.</Пункт>
            <Улица>ул.</Улица>
            <Дом>0</Дом>
            <Корп></Корп>
            <Оф></Оф>
          </АдрРегИП>
          <СведДокУдЛичн>
            <ВидДокКод></ВидДокКод>
            <ВидДокНаименование>Паспорт</ВидДокНаименование>
            <СерияДок>0</СерияДок>
            <НомДок>0</НомДок>
            <ДатВыдачиДок>0</ДатВыдачиДок>
            <КемВыданДок>кем-то</КемВыданДок>
            <КодПодр>000-000</КодПодр>
          </СведДокУдЛичн>
          <ДатаРождения></ДатаРождения>
          <МестоРожд>
            <КодОКСМ></КодОКСМ>
            <СтранаНаименование></СтранаНаименование>
            <КодСубъектаПоОКАТО></КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>
            <Район></Район>
            <Пункт></Пункт>
          </МестоРожд>
          <КодОКСМ></КодОКСМ>
          <СтранаНаименование></СтранаНаименование>
          <ПризнакПубЛицо>0</ПризнакПубЛицо>
        </СведФЛИП>
      </Раздел1.1>
```

Comment: А как foreach делали, что он не проканал?

Comment: Один из последних вариантов был такой, но это видимо вообще не верно.foreach (СообщОтказ_115ФЗ items in Obj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(items.ИнформЧасть[0].Раздел11[0].НомерЗаписи.ToString());
            }

Comment: попробуйте `foreach (var x in Obj.ИнформЧасть) { foreach (var y in x.Раздел11) { Console.WriteLine(y.НомерЗаписи); } }`

Comment: Покажите класс, в который вы десериализовать пытаетесь

Comment: @Vlad Спасибо большое. Все получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно либо пройтись по всем элементам массива, либо обращаться к нужным по индексу. Пример обхода всех элементов:

```
foreach (var inf in Obj.ИнформЧасть)
{ 
    foreach (var section in inf.Раздел11) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(section.НомерЗаписи);
        Console.WriteLine(section.СведЮЛ.НаимЮЛ); 
    } 
}
```

Либо можно совместить с Linq:

```
foreach (var section in Obj.ИнформЧасть.SelectMany(_ => _.Раздел11))
{
    Console.WriteLine(section.НомерЗаписи);
    Console.WriteLine(section.СведЮЛ.НаимЮЛ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться `System.Xml.Linq`

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

List<Firm> firms = new List<Firm>();
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("ИнформЧасть").Elements("Раздел1.1"))
{
    var firm = new Firm
    {
        Number = item.Element("НомерЗаписи").Value,
        Name = item.Element("СведЮЛ")?.Element("НаимЮЛ")?.Value
    };

    firms.Add(firm);
}
```